# Counter in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count

so I'm quite new to PHP and I want to implement a counter. My scenario is for example, if I type the word "dog" in the search bar of the site I'm developing, it will display the list of all dogs in my database and on top of the list, it will display how many matches are there, say "Number of dogs: ".. Here is an excerpt of the code so far. Apart from listing the matches (from another working function I made), it doesn't do anything.

```
function countStores($conn, $match)
{

   $columns = "FieldResearcher, Mall, NameOfStore, Floor, Building, AMEX";
   $table          = "final";
   $conditions   = "NameOfStore LIKE '%$match%' ";

    $query = "SELECT count(NameOfStore) FROM $table where $conditions";


    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if ($result == FALSE)
    {
        echo "Invalid query: " . $conn->error;
        echo "<br/>";
        return;
    }

    echo "Number of Stores: " . $query;

     $actionStr = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];                          // TODO

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) )
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++)
        {
            echo "<td>" . $row[$i] . "</td>";
        }

        echo "<td>";                                            // TODO
        echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"$actionStr\">";    // TODO
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"code\" value=\"$row[0]\">";
        //echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"BUY!\">";          // TODO
        echo "</form>";                                         // TODO
        echo "</td>";                                           // TODO
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: just use `num_rows`, itsin the manual

Answer (score 0):

```
$q="SELECT count(*) as dogsno 
    FROM tblanimal 
    where name='dog'";
```

It will count the number of dogs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate through how many rows returned in your query. Just use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Try doing it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name", $dbConn);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM $table WHERE $conditions";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row['count'];
```